# Convert hour to date-time

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data frame with hour stamp and corresponding temperature measured. The measurements are taken at random intervals over time continuously. I would like to convert the hours to respective date-time and temperature measured. My data frame looks like this: (The measurement started at 20/05/2016)

```
Time, Temp
09.25,28
10.35,28.2
18.25,29
23.50,30
01.10,31
12.00,36
02.00,25
```

I would like to create a data.frame with respective date-time and Temp like below:

```
Time, Temp
2016-05-20 09:25,28
2016-05-20 10:35,28.2
2016-05-20 18:25,29
2016-05-20 23:50,30
2016-05-21 01:10,31
2016-05-21 12:00,36
2016-05-22 02:00,25
```

I am thankful for any comments and tips on the packages or functions in R, I can have a look to do this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are your input strings or floating point numbers?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. If are asking about the time, "09.25" refers to 9 hours 25 minutes ie 09:25

Comment: He's asking how `Time` is actually formatted in your data frame. Is it numeric or string? In your example, you've listed `Time` in two different ways, e.g., `09.25` and `02:00`. Please paste in your data sample using `dput` or at least show us the output of `str(mydata)`. Also, in your example, `Time` contains only a time of day. Where does the date come from?

Comment: Oh yes, apologies for the wrong formatting. I have edited the time. The time stamp is numeric. The date mentioned is actual start date of the measurement.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like to assign the corresponding date to your variable Time and Temp?

Comment: @Miha yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution in base R:

```
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste('2016-05-20', sprintf('%05.2f',df$Time)), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M', tz = 'GMT'))
df$Time <- df$Time + cumsum(c(0,diff(df$Time)) < 0) * 86400  # 86400 = 60 * 60 * 24
```

which gives:

```
> df
                 Time Temp
1 2016-05-20 09:25:00 28.0
2 2016-05-20 10:35:00 28.2
3 2016-05-20 18:25:00 29.0
4 2016-05-20 23:50:00 30.0
5 2016-05-21 01:10:00 31.0
6 2016-05-21 12:00:00 36.0
7 2016-05-22 02:00:00 25.0
```

---

An alternative with `data.table` (off course you can also use `cumsum` with `diff` instead of `rleid` & `shift`):

```
setDT(df)[, Time := as.POSIXct(strptime(paste('2016-05-20', sprintf('%05.2f',Time)), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M', tz = 'GMT')) +
            (rleid(Time < shift(Time, fill = Time[1]))-1) * 86400]
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(strptime(paste('2016-05-20', 
                                          sprintf('%05.2f',Time)), 
                                    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M', tz = 'GMT')) + 
           cumsum(c(0,diff(Time)) < 0)*86400)
```

which will both give the same result.

---

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text='Time, Temp
09.25,28
10.35,28.2
18.25,29
23.50,30
01.10,31
12.00,36
02.00,25', header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom date format combined with some code that detects when a new day begins (assuming the first measurement takes place earlier in the day than the last measurement of the previous day).

```
# starting day
start_date = "2016-05-20"

values=read.csv('values.txt', colClasses=c("character",NA))
last=c(0,values$Time[1:nrow(values)-1])
day=cumsum(values$Time<last)

Time = strptime(paste(start_date,values$Time), "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M")
Time = Time + day*86400
values$Time = Time
```